# Resuming Minecraft Server Console

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

I'm running a Paper 1.14.3 server on a VPS running Ubuntu 18.04.

When I run `restart` on the Paper server or lose my SSH connection to the VPS, I no longer see Paper's console, so I'm unable to interact with the server anymore. Is there any way to "resume" the console process on Linux? In other words, is there any way to make Paper's console the main focus of the user again?

I know the Paper server is still running. `htop` shows that Paper is still running, and I can connect to the hosted server just fine.

To clarify, Paper's restart function `stops` the server, then runs `run.sh`. My run.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/minecraft/server;

java -Xms1024M -Xmx1536M -jar paper.jar
```

I've tried resuming a screen using `screen -r`, but Paper's console isn't happening in a separate screen. I've also tried running `kill -CONT [pid of some paper processes]`, but nothing happens, likely because the Paper processes aren't suspended.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the server is still running and you can connect to it then some process has ownership of it. You indicate that you were using screen so that's likely where that is (but I don't know enough about screen to answer). Regardless, you should include a full list of the steps you took to start the server here so that we have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on superuser.com, unixSE or AskUbuntu.